LastPass extension not showing the icon of my site
Lastpass extension not showing the my website fav icon image and just showing initials of the name.
I have added fav icon and og:image tag on my website but lastpass extension not showing the image and just showing initials of the name. Any help would be appreciated.


First, check the browser cache and refresh your site,

The favicon file should be in standard format, such as 16x16 or 32x32 pixels,

Check the favicon link in the HTML code,
and wait a few minutes



I have tried these solutions already. Favicon is correct size.

I have tried to check in multiple systems. So, this is not cache problem
I have removed login from extension and added again
I have tested with other extensions as well
None of these solutions are working.

